# Users not appearing on leaderboard mongoose discordjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, leaderboard

I created a leaderboard that sorts users from richest to poorest in discord.js and mongoose. Some users aren’t appearing on the leaderboard when they are supposed to be on it. This guy has trillions but isn’t on it
[image]

Here is my code for my leaderboard

```
const { Message, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js')
const Client = require('../bot')
const stats = require('./stats')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const commaNumber = require('comma-number')

module.exports = {
    name: `lb`,
    aliases:['leaderboard'],

    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
run: async(client, message, args) => {
        
    const users = await client.schema.find()
    const Userid = users.User
    const lb = users
              .slice(0)
              .sort(({ Bobux: a }, { Bobux: b }) => b - a)
              .map(
                
                ({ User, Bobux }, pos) => `${pos + 1}. <@${User}> - ${commaNumber(Bobux)} Bobux`,
              );

          const newnew =     lb.slice(0, 15)
              const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('Global Leaderboard For Most Bobux - Top 15')
              .setDescription(newnew)
              .setColor('RANDOM')
    message.channel.send(embed)
    

},
timeout: 5000
}
```

Here is the schema code. It’s in the main bot.js file

```
 this.schema = this.mongoose.model(
            `economy`,
            new this.mongoose.Schema({
                User: String,
                Bobux: Number,

            })
        );



        const self = this
        this.economy = {
            async getBal(User) {
                return await self.schema.findOne({
                    User
                }).then((d) => d ? d.Bobux : 0)
            },

            async addBal(User, Bobux) {
                return await self.schema.findOne({ User }, async(err, data) => {
                    if(err) throw err
                    if(data) {
                        data.Bobux += Number(Bobux)
                    } else {
                        data = new self.schema({ User, Bobux })
                    }
                    data.save()
                })
            },
            async subBal(User, Bobux) {
                return await self.schema.findOne({ User }, async(err, data) => {
                    if(err) throw err
                    if(data) {
                        data.Bobux -= Number(Bobux)
                    } else {
                        data = new self.schema({ User, Bobux })
                    }
                    data.save()
                })
            }
```

I am not sure why users are not appearing on the leaderboard

Sorry for the long post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you mention and your client ( discord application ) is not caching that user in your server yet so they don't display with you only. Behaviour is same with other client if they don't cache that user yet
I would prefer you fetch guildMember and display their nickname or username with tag in leaderboard ( not mention) for well display

Comment: I dont really understand what you are trying to say @HellCatVn


Sorry can you please rephrase

Comment: I removed the mention and just added an id but it still doesn't work

Comment: I will edit some code for you. But can you `console.log(User)` at`({ User, Bobux }, pos) => { console.log(User)});`

Comment: It logs many user ids like this. It might be logging all the user ids from my 3500 users in the database. Here is the first few. Edit: I counted the word count and it is exactly 996 ids
635588494533722113
838248101231329281
780590882977349662
811796590124859393
818573703427391581
790131656534261761
825175841297530890
680264043587698840
807538068327235605
857556484074242078

Comment: You have too many err here you need mongo db to sort and get top user first instead of get all try to do it and edit your post first then we come to this question

Comment: How do I get the top user?

Comment: That is base on your filter which condition is consider as a top user. learn how to using mongoose first